# Relaxation of notion of positive definite function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is called *positive definite* (in the semigroup sense) if for all $n\geq 1$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ pairwise different the matrix $(f(x_i+x_j))_{i,j=1}^n$ is positive definite. Such functions have a nice characterization by (a version of) Bochner's theorem.

Now I am interested in the following relaxation of this notion: Fix $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We say that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is *$k$-positive* if for all $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb{R}$ pairwise different the matrix $(f(x_i+x_j))_{i,j=1}^k$ is positive definite.

For instance $1$-positive means that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Being $2$-positive means additionally that $\log(f)$ is strictly midpoint convex.

In general, it is clear that $k$-positive definite implies $(k-1)$-positive definite, and the above example shows that the converse is not always true. My question is the following: Is it true that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a $k$-positive function which is not $(k+1)$-positive?

Comment: Not an answer, just wanted to let you know that the Theorem 6.2 from your first paragraph is generally known as Bochner's Theorem and can be formulated for functions on any locally compact abelian group.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I bet the answer is yes, and I am sure one can find it out it in Karlin's *Total Positivity*. (This is called *totally positive of order $k$* there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$For real $c$ and $x$, let
$$f_c(x):=f(x)-c,$$
where $f(x):=e^{x^2/2}$. Note that $f$ is the moment generating function of the standard normal distribution and thus a mixture of exponential functions. Since the exponential functions are positive semidefinite (in the semigroup sense), $f$ is also positive semidefinite. With some further effort, one should be able to show that $f$ is positive  definite.

By Theorem 2.5 on p. 55, Theorem 5.3 on p. 65, and Theorem 8.1 on p. 78 of [Karlin - Total positivity, vol. I](https://www.worldcat.org/title/total-positivity/oclc/160219), for $f_c$ to be $r$-positive semidefinite it is sufficient that the Hankel determinant
$$d_{k,c}(x):=d_{f;k,c}(x):=\det((f_c^{(i+j)}(x))_{0\le i,j\le k-1})$$
be $>0$ for all $k\in[r]:=\{1,\dots,r\}$ and necessary that this determinant be $\ge0$ for all $k\in[r]$. Note that
$$d_{k,c}(x)=d_{k,0}(x)-c\tilde d_k(x),$$
where
$$\tilde d_k(x):=d_{f'';k-1,0}(x)=\det((f^{(i+j)}(x))_{1\le i,j\le k-1});$$
note also that, similarly to $d_{k,0}(x)\ge0$ for real $x$, we have $\tilde d_k(x)\ge0$ for real $x$ (and, likely, $\tilde d_k(x)>0$ for real $x$).

Let
$$c_k:=\sup\{c\colon d_{k,c}(x)\ge0\ \forall x\in\R\}
=\inf_{x\in\R}\frac{d_{k,0}(x)}{\tilde d_k(x)}. $$
We have
$$c_1=1>c_2=\frac{\sqrt e}2=0.82\ldots>c_3=\frac23=0.66\ldots.$$
Moreover, it appears that $c_k>c_{k+1}$ for all natural $k$.

It will then follow that $f_c$ is $r$-positive semidefinite but not $(r+1)$-positive semidefinite if $c_{r+1}<c<c_r$. (One may also note here that, for $f_c$ to be $r$-positive semidefinite but not $(r+1)$-positive semidefinite, it is necessary that $c_{r+1}\le c\le c_r$.)

---

*Remark:* It appears that
$$d_{k,0}(x)\overset{\text{(?)}}=(k-1)\\\$\,e^{k x^2/2},$$
where $n\\\$:=\prod_{j=1}^n j!$, the superfactorial.
It also appears that
$$\tilde d_k(x)\overset{\text{(?)}}=P_{k-1}(x^2)e^{(k-1)x^2/2},$$
where $P_{k-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$. I do not know much more about the polynomials $P_{k-1}$.

---

The conjecture that $c_k>c_{k+1}$ for all natural $k$ and the above remark are illustrated by the following image of a Mathematica notebook (click on the image to magnify it):

[image]

Comment: Your link for Karlin's book goes to a review of that book, rather than the book itself.  Was that intentional?

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comment. This link should now be corrected. Thank you also for your edit.